# Let data access layer perform 2 DB operations vs potentially let DB operation fail

Tags: node.js, postgresql, rest, database-design

I'm building a REST API using a *router *->* controller *->* service *->* data access* architecture.

Most tutorials/sample projects do creations and updates like this (in the DAO):

1. Retrieve existing data from DB
2. Create/update record in the DB

For example this code in a freecodecamp.com node.js REST API tutorial:

```
const createNewWorkout = (newWorkout) => {
  try {
    const isAlreadyAdded =
      DB.workouts.findIndex((workout) => workout.name === newWorkout.name) > -1;
    if (isAlreadyAdded) {
      throw {
        status: 400,
        message: `Workout with the name '${newWorkout.name}' already exists`,
      };
    }
    DB.workouts.push(newWorkout);
    saveToDatabase(DB);
    return newWorkout;
  } catch (error) {
    throw { status: error?.status || 500, message: error?.message || error };
  }
};

const updateOneWorkout = (workoutId, changes) => {
  try {
    const isAlreadyAdded =
      DB.workouts.findIndex((workout) => workout.name === changes.name) > -1;
    if (isAlreadyAdded) {
      throw {
        status: 400,
        message: `Workout with the name '${changes.name}' already exists`,
      };
    }
    const indexForUpdate = DB.workouts.findIndex(
      (workout) => workout.id === workoutId
    );
    if (indexForUpdate === -1) {
      throw {
        status: 400,
        message: `Can't find workout with the id '${workoutId}'`,
      };
    }
    const updatedWorkout = {
      ...DB.workouts[indexForUpdate],
      ...changes,
      updatedAt: new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: "UTC" }),
    };
    DB.workouts[indexForUpdate] = updatedWorkout;
    saveToDatabase(DB);
    return updatedWorkout;
  } catch (error) {
    throw { status: error?.status || 500, message: error?.message || error };
  }
};
```

Database operations are expensive in terms of server resource, however. Wouldn't it be better to just try the creation/update, let the operation fail if need be (record with the primary key already exists, update is missing required fields etc.), and catch the error? Maybe encapsulate everything in a stored procedure, which may indeed still first retrieve the data to do some checks but which can be optimized by the database?

Comment: 1) Postgres has [On Conflict](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) that covers a good deal or INSERT or UPDATE.  Postgres 15+ also has [Merge](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-merge.html) which is another way of attacking the issue. 2) What makes you think that the catching the error, then dealing with it would be more efficient then checking before hand?

Comment: That you for your response! Yes, modern DB's do have multiple ways of handling the issue. Catching the error wouldn't be more efficient, no. But checking beforehand happens EVERY TIME, catching the error and dealing with it happens only every time there's an issue (which cannot be more often than every time, and is probably occurring far less).

Comment: The  end user needs to know what is there to either UPDATE existing information or INSERT information that does not exist. I am not sure how that can be done without reference to the existing data.  Otherwise you have users blindly hitting the database with random data.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Yes you do need to do a SELECT query to show the data to the user but OP wants to prevent doing another SELECT before every INSERT/UPDATE to validate if the INSERT/UPDATE will pass.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably move all the validation you want to do into the database using foreign keys, check constraints and triggers which raise an exception if validation fails and then handle the failure/success in your application code.

It could be a lot more efficient if the validation of your INSERT/UPDATE depends on a lot of data, especially if you would use multiple queries to fetch that data. Moving the validation into the DB will save you network round-trips. It is possible the database will optimize querying the data needed for validation and the validation operations themselves but most likely saving network round-trips will be the biggest time save.

Comment: You're right, network round-trips are an even greater time cost than database access. However, since I'm dealing with an api server and database on the same server that's not really a concern (within the context of a single request).